# What versions of android can request location having the GPS off?

Tags: android, location

Android phone with API 23 allows me to get the location using the network provider even when the GPS is off. What versions stopped doing this?

Comment: Define "GPS is off".  Do you mean that location tracking in the setting is set to wifi?  In which case you should still be able to get network position.  Or its set to off?  In which case it was never possible, although there may be an implementation bug which allowed it.  Also make sure you're requesting runtime permission for the correct type of tracking, that sounds like about the right timeframe for those to have been added.

Comment: What I mean by "GPS is off" is that the location tracking is turned off by swiping down from the top of the screen and press on the location icon to set it off.

Comment: In that case it should never have been giving you a network location if location was completely off.

Comment: However dispite turning off GPS from the notification pannel, SDK 23 still allows to get the location using the netwrok provider.

Comment: I would suspect that whatever platform you tested it on had a bug that allowed it rather than that being expected behavior.  Location off means location off.  Perhaps your UI has a "GPS off" only that doesn't turn off all location.  In which case the answer would tie to your custom UI (as pretty much every vendor customizes it), not the Android version.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend caution on this, the Android system is setup to block just this type of thing from happening. It's a user privacy thing and can get you kicked off the Google Developer Platform for violating user privacy and can open you up to a lot of legal troubles.

See:

https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/9888077?hl=en

https://android-developers.googleblog.com/2020/02/how-we-fought-bad-apps-and-malicious.html